# Java - Easiest way to get single property from each object in a list/array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

Say I have a person object with properties such as `name`, `hair color`, and `eye color`. I have the following array `Person[] people` that contains instances of person objects.

I know I can get the `name` property of one the `Person` objects with

```
// create a new instance of Person
Person george = new Person('george','brown','blue');
// <<< make a people array that contains the george instance here... >>>
// access the name property
String georgesName = people[0].name;
```

But what if I want to access the `name` property of everyone without using indexes? For example, to create an array or list of just names or hair color? Do I have to manually iterate through my `people` array? Or is there something cool in Java like `String[] peopleNames = people.name`?

Comment: Pretty much you have to iterate.  You can use streams but for small lists they are not efficient.

Comment: You are using an imperative language. Therefore, explicit iterations are the way to go. If you don't like writing loops, go with a functional language such as Scala. There you could use a simple one-liner and have it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the difference between the two, perhaps as an answer?

Comment: @MatthiasFax, you do not need to explicitly iterate if using Java 8's streaming API, which is functional in nature.

Comment: @jrahhali Yes, you can use streams, but they are not performant. Java is not made for it, the Streaming API is just built "around", not from the bottom up. They are not performant and in my view also ugly and difficult to read.

Comment: @MatthiasFax, I agree with you that the streaming API is built around the core language and not from the bottom up, but it does allow you to use functional idioms, and therefore, not have to explicit iterate.  The 'explicit iterating' was the only point I was addressing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two options:

1. Iteration
2. Streams (*Java 8*)

***Iteration***

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person p : people) {
    names.add(p.name);
}
```

***Streams***

```
String[] names = Arrays.stream(people).map(p -> p.name).toArray(size -> new String[people.length]);
```

Comment: Since OP would accept `List` as result type (*"For example, to create an array or **list** of just names or hair color"*), a for-each loop adding to a `List<String>` would be another nice option to show, for completeness, i.e. `for (Person p : people) { names.add(p.name); }`

Comment: @Andreas ah yup! I was gunna do a `List<String>` initially but didn't notice that in the question

Answer (score 6):

java 8:

```
String[] names = Arrays.asStream(people).map(Person::getName).asArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> vendorIdList = ledgersList.stream().map(Ledger::getVendorId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

You are seeking a functional feature in an initially imperative-only language Java. As already mentioned in other answers, since Java 8, you also have functional elements (e.g., streams). However, they are not yet recommended to be used. This [blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/) explains the disadvantages of streams over loops (i.e., performance, readability, maintainability).

If you are looking for functional and safe code without such major implications, try Scala:

```
case class Person(name: String)
val persons = Array(Person("george"), Person("michael"), Person("dexter"))
val personNames = persons.map(_.name)
```

The main difference is that this Scala code is simple to read and it is comparably performant as a Java code that uses a loop because the translated Scala-to-Java code uses a while loop internally.